# Is it possible to use SQL Server as DB Store for NATS streaming server?

Tags: sql-server, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I plan to create a nats streaming server and use SQL Server as DB store. is that possible?

I am not sure what to put on the DB store config

Answer (score 0):

NATS Streaming Server uses only MySQL or Postgres drivers. The configuration of the db source will depend on the driver you select.

See [this](https://docs.nats.io/nats-streaming-server/configuring/persistence/sql_store) for more information about SQL Store support.

Comment: Is it strictly Postgres? Or anything Postgres compatible?